# Windows Server 2016 Active Directory: Granting Admin to a User for only specific machines

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016, organizational-unit

I have granted local admin to several machines for an active directory user who requested / needed this access. I did not want to grant admin to the entire domain and server, but instead to only specific terminals.

I found a post online about granting local administrator for specific machines using group policy management and group policy management editor. (Found below)

https://support.dincloud.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-make-a-domain-user-the-local-administrator-for-all-pcs

I created an OU (i.e. contains All Computers in domain) and created another OU (i.e. contains Specific Computers) inside that contains the computers I wanted to grant admin access for this user to.

I applied the custom Local Admin GPO and linked it to the Specific Computers OU inside of the All Computers OU. This seems to have worked to grant Local admin to those specific computers for this user...

My question being, what If I wanted to at another time give someone else admin access only to 2-3 of the computers inside the the Specific computers OU?

Is there an easier way to do this? I played around with a security group (added specific computers) and tried to have this be the method to grant admin access but could not figure it out.

Please let me know what you think.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is easier, you be the judge.
Run a PowerShell script enumerating all computers in AD, and create a group for each of them. If you want to go crazy, you can make groups for any role. Example:

YourOrg.Computers.computername.Administrators
YourOrg.Computers.computername.Remote Desktop Users
YourOrg.Computers.computername.Users
etc.

Then you run a script connecting each computer to the ad group, based on the hostname and local group name, you can "guess" witch ad group name you need. Voila, you have moved administration to AD. With a bit of skills, you make the "enrol all computers script" in two-tree hours.

By using elements of this, you can make a "enrol single computer" script, making the groups, connection to remote computer and attaching them.

You can also consider to remove Domain Admins and Domain Users from the computers, for increased security and privacy on each client computer.

Auditing access is now super easy.
Giving access is centralized.

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions on GPOs.

Standards permissions grant the right to "apply group policy" to any authenticated user (which includes computer accounts); so it applies to whatever user or computer is in its scope (the OU to which the GPO is linked).

You can change those permission to only allow the GPO to be applied to a specific group; this with allow you to manage who/what is influenced by that GPO regardless of the OU it's located in.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/assign-security-group-filters-to-the-gpo